# Require assistance with linking glfw in visual code

Tags: glfw

I'm currently facing difficulties in establishing the necessary linkage for the GLFW library within my Visual Studio Code environment, configured for C++ development. Despite my efforts, successful integration seems to elude me. In an effort to provide clarity on the structure of my project, I've included an image below for reference. Your guidance in overcoming these linking challenges would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error: GLFW\glfw3.h: No such file or directory

i am using mingw64 as my compilier.

````
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:/Software/mingw/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/dependencies/include/GLFW"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "D:/Software/mingw/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
} ```

``` {
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\Software\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },  
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
} ```

``` #include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "GLFW Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
} ```

[The image of my project setup!][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spks8.png
````